# Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, browser-cache, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir webdriver to click on all the links with the same title on a webpage.

```
browser.links(:title => 'Hide week').each(&:click)
```

However, it sometimes happens and I get this error message:

```
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

I need the program to click on a 'turn editing on' button first, then the page will reload and configuration buttons/icons will show. Then each(&:click) should click on the buttons/icons. Is there another way of clicking on a group of links that can avoid 'Element not found in the cache'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way apart from initializing the elements again, before clicking them.

Comment: Thanks, Sham. However, what elements should I initialize again? I just found that it crashes after clicking on the first button/icon correctly. Should I re-initialize links?

Comment: Yes. If you have performed a click which does the page refresh and if you are trying to click on an element that are on the same page then you need to re-initialize them.